# Apache spark Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077 in Google cloud cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to start an apache spark cluster in Google cloud with 1 Master and 4 workers. However, when I run **start-all.sh** It shows that all nodes are starting without any error.

```
sparkuser@master:/opt/spark/logs$ start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out
worker1: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker1.out
worker3: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker3.out
worker4: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker4.out
worker2: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker2.out
sparkuser@master:/opt/spark/logs$
```

When I check the log file, the Master is running. But none of the workers are running. What could be the issue?

**spark-env.sh** for workers

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST="master"
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs
```

**spark-env.sh** for master

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST="master"
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs
```

The error on the log file of worker:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://master:7077
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
22/11/07 10:20:13 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 18908@worker2
22/11/07 10:20:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
22/11/07 10:20:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
22/11/07 10:20:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
22/11/07 10:20:13 WARN Utils: Your hostname, worker2 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.178.0.5 instead (on interface ens4)
22/11/07 10:20:13 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
22/11/07 10:20:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sparkuser
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sparkuser
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(sparkuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sparkuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 46335.
22/11/07 10:20:14 INFO Worker: Worker decommissioning not enabled.
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 10.178.0.5:46335 with 2 cores, 6.8 GiB RAM
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 3.2.2
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO Worker: Spark home: /opt/spark
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.worker.
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://worker2.c.apache-spark-project-363713.internal:8081
22/11/07 10:20:15 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:20:24 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
22/11/07 10:20:24 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:20:33 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 2)
22/11/07 10:20:33 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:20:42 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 3)
22/11/07 10:20:42 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:20:51 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 4)
22/11/07 10:20:51 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:21:00 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 5)
22/11/07 10:21:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:21:09 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 6)
22/11/07 10:21:09 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:22:00 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 7)
22/11/07 10:22:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:22:15 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
22/11/07 10:22:15 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
22/11/07 10:22:15 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:285)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
22/11/07 10:22:51 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 8)
22/11/07 10:22:51 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:23:42 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 9)
22/11/07 10:23:42 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:24:33 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 10)
22/11/07 10:24:33 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:24:51 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
22/11/07 10:24:51 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
22/11/07 10:24:51 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:285)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
22/11/07 10:25:24 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 11)
22/11/07 10:25:24 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:26:15 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 12)
22/11/07 10:26:15 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:27:06 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 13)
22/11/07 10:27:06 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:27:24 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
22/11/07 10:27:24 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
22/11/07 10:27:24 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:285)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
22/11/07 10:27:57 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 14)
22/11/07 10:27:57 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:28:48 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 15)
22/11/07 10:28:48 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:29:39 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 16)
22/11/07 10:29:39 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
22/11/07 10:29:57 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
22/11/07 10:29:57 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
22/11/07 10:29:57 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to master/35.216.27.9:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:285)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more
22/11/07 10:30:30 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

Comment: Why do you think that `master` is a valid host ? You are clearly failing to connect to your `master` host. It seems to be purely a network issue and  can be caused because of 100's of reasons such as wrong address, port configuration, firewall configuration, subnet configuration etc.

Comment: Why not use DataProc, which is already pre-configured for Spark? In any case, the "local IP" should be the LAN IP within the VPC, not `127.0.0.1`. Similarly, `nc -vz 35.216.27.9 7077` will test that the port is actually accessible.

Comment: @sarveshseri in the host file I have the master and its external Ip address. And I can ssh and SCP between the master and the worker nodes. Isn't that enough for the nodes to communicate with each other? I don't have much experience with this google cloud-based Apache spark. In my local cluster, I didn't need to have a lot of configurations and my program is running properly with minimal configurations. And regarding the firewall, I have turned it off. I don't understand why the connection is failing.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was using DataProc, however, it has built-in YARN, which I don't use for managing clusters. I can just use apache standalone cluster manager. And I was getting a lot of errors during the **spark-submit**. Didn't feel like continuing it, thus I switched to the VM instances. I do have a local cluster with 3 nodes, 1 master, and 2 workers. However, I want to see how my program works with the increase in the number of executors so I am trying to adopt the Google Cloud service. DataProc has pre-configured spark, but it just doesn't work for me looking at the time constraints.

Comment: Running a reliable Spark Cluster in cloud environment is not a straightforward task. I would suggest seeking help from someone who knows how to do it. Or, you can use something like DataProc or Spark on Kubernetes, which is much easier to get running.

Comment: Dataproc is still "VMs". If you're getting errors with Spark submit, then I'd suggest you post those errors rather than start from scratch. Spark standalone is much less commonly used than YARN or Kubernetes, in my experience, but you still need to do basic network debugging, as I commented. No, SSH/SCP is not used by Spark

Comment: If you're referring to your previous ClassNotFound error, you'll have the same problem with Spark standalone because that was an issue with your JAR packaging/Maven definition, not the Spark setup